# create two users from one form_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, models

I have an application that gathers information about two different users.

Is there a way in rails to make one form to gather information for two users?

Rails 3, OsX10.6, Ruby 1.9.2

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this but you should use [`form_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) and [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) instead. See episodes [165](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple), [196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), [197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), and [198](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually) of Railscasts for more info. Those screencasts are for Rails 2, but they can be adopted to work with Rails 3.

Comment: Thanks Behrang that will help me al lot.